# Select from a 3-dimensional array with a 2-dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I have two arrays:

- `a`: a 3-dimensional source array (*N x M x 2*)
- `b`: a 2-dimensional index array (*N x M*) containing 0 and 1s.

I want to use the indices in `b` to select the corresponding elements of `a` in its third dimension. The resulting array should have the dimensions *N x M*. Here is the example as code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array( # dims: 3x3x2
    [[[ 0,  1],
     [ 2,  3],
     [ 4,  5]],
    [[ 6,  7],
     [ 8,  9],
     [10, 11]],
    [[12, 13],
     [14, 15],
     [16, 17]]]
)
b = np.array( # dims: 3x3
    [[1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]]
)

# select the elements in a according to b
# to achieve this result:
desired = np.array(
  [[ 1,  3,  5],
   [ 7,  9, 11],
   [13, 15, 17]]
)
```

At first, I thought this must have a simple solution but I could not find one at all. Since I would like to port it to tensorflow, I would appreciate if somebody knows a numpy-type solution for this.

**Edit:** The third dimension of `a` might contain more than two elements. Hence, `b` might also contain indices different from 0 and 1 - it is not a boolean mask.

Comment: could you elaborate on the logic for selection? i cannot see any relation between `b` and the end result.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh For each element `x` at position `(m, n)` in `b`, the output array should, at position `(m, n)`, be equal to `a[m, n, x]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`np.take_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array(
    [[[ 0,  1],
      [ 2,  3],
      [ 4,  5]],
     [[ 6,  7],
      [ 8,  9],
      [10, 11]],
     [[12, 13],
      [14, 15],
      [16, 17]]])
b = np.array(
    [[1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1]])
print(np.take_along_axis(a, b[..., np.newaxis], axis=-1)[..., 0])
# [[ 1  3  5]
#  [ 7  9 11]
#  [13 15 17]]
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `np.where` for this:

```
np.where(b, a[:, :, 1], a[:, :, 0])
```

Output:

```
array([[ 1,  3,  5],
       [ 7,  9, 11],
       [13, 15, 17]])
```

Comment: I like your use of `np.where` here but the last dimension of `a` might contain more than two elements - so I really need the numerical indices from `b` not just as a boolean mask. Sorry, I should clarify this in my question.

Comment: @mrzo Then the `take_along_axis` answer is most probably what you want.

Answer (score 2):

As @jdehesa sugests, we can use [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) to obtain the indices for the first two axes:

```
ax0, ax1 = np.ogrid[:b.shape[0], :b.shape[1]]
```

And then we can use `b` to directly index along the last axis. Note that `ax0` and `ax1` will be broadcast to the shape of `b`:

```
desired = a[ax0, ax1 ,b] 

print(desired)
array([[ 1,  3,  5],
       [ 7,  9, 11],
       [13, 15, 17]])
```

Comment: You can also get the same with `ax0, ax1 = np.ogrid[:b.shape[0], :b.shape[1]]` and then `desired = a[ax0, ax1, b]` (broadcasting the indices).

Comment: Ah yes tha's much nicer, thanks for suggesting @jdehesa

Answer (score 2):

I added some solutions for tensorflow.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[[ 0,  1],[ 2,  3],[ 4,  5]],
                 [[ 6,  7],[ 8,  9],[10, 11]],
                 [[12, 13],[14, 15],[16, 17]]],dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.constant([[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1]],dtype=tf.int32)

# 1. use tf.gather_nd
colum,row = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(a.shape[0]),tf.range(a.shape[1]))
idx = tf.stack([row, colum, b], axis=-1) # Thanks for @jdehesa's suggestion
result1 = tf.gather_nd(a,idx)

# 2. use tf.reduce_sum
mask = tf.one_hot(b,depth=a.shape[-1],dtype=tf.float32)
result2 = tf.reduce_sum(a*mask,axis=-1)

# 3. use tf.boolean_mask
mask = tf.one_hot(b,depth=a.shape[-1],dtype=tf.float32)
result3 = tf.reshape(tf.boolean_mask(a,mask),b.shape)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('method 1: \n',sess.run(result1))
    print('method 2: \n',sess.run(result2))
    print('method 3: \n',sess.run(result3))

method 1: 
 [[ 1.  3.  5.]
 [ 7.  9. 11.]
 [13. 15. 17.]]
method 2: 
 [[ 1.  3.  5.]
 [ 7.  9. 11.]
 [13. 15. 17.]]
method 3: 
 [[ 1.  3.  5.]
 [ 7.  9. 11.]
 [13. 15. 17.]]
```

Comment: Nice. Just as a suggestion, you can make `idx = tf.concat([row[:,:,tf.newaxis],colum[:,:,tf.newaxis],b[:,:,tf.newaxis]],axis=-1)` a bit more concise with `idx = tf.stack([row, colum, b], axis=-1)`.